# Git push all but one file, without deletion

Tags: git

## hello there

I have been trying to push some files to github.
Here's the idea:

github repo-

FILE 1
FILE 2
FILE 3
FILE 4
FILE 5
**generic** config. file

Now imagine that i cloned this repo, and modified all the files like this:

FILE 1.2
FILE 2.2
FILE 3.2
FILE 4.2
FILE 5.2
**SPECIFIC** config. file

Now, the config file is necessary to run on my machine (linux for example), but my partner has another kind of config. So I want to push all my new files, except for this config file. But i also need my generic config file in the repo, for the people that are cloning the repo now.

i have tried this:

```
git add .
git checkout .\config.txt
git commit -m 'ravr'
```

but it did not work, so i tried this

```
git add -u
git reset config.txt
git commit -m 'ceowhnv'
```

No fix.

```
git add -- . :! ./config.txt
git commit -m 'iwrnv'
```

Also failed. I have also tried those with the full location of the file, and, in some cases (such as the checkout one), the generic config. file was wiped out of the repo

What is the most efficient way to do this, and keep the generic config file in the repo?

Comment: Add the config file to .gitignore

Comment: @Christoph: Adding files to `.gitignore` only works for *untracked* files.

Comment: @Greg but you can remove them from tracking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell Git to ignore changes to a tracked file in your local repository with the following command:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged config.txt
```

Then, you can use commands like `git add -u` and Git will not add `config.txt` even if it has changed locally. This does not change how the repository works in other clones, so you have to run this command in each clone (if you want it).

To undo this flag, use:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged config.txt
```

Another approach is to commit a "generic" config file to your repository under a different name. For example, if you store the generic one as `config.txt.generic`, then your local changes to `config.txt` are unrelated to what's in the repository. In this case you would need user instructions or an automated script to copy `config.txt.generic` to `config.txt` when your program is run for the first time.

Comment: This is _per repo_ so every user will have to do the same thing on their repo.

Comment: @eftshift0: Yes, thanks I'll add that note to the answer.